# What does $2^{\mathbb R}$ mean?

Tags: measure-theory, functions, notation

Does it mean $2^{\mathbb R}= P{ (\mathbb R)}$ where $P$ is the power set.

What does it mean in terms of functions like $l : 2^{\mathbb R} \rightarrow [0,+ \infty]$?

Comment: That is what it means to me (power set).  Any set can be the domain of a function, so I'm not sure what you are getting at in the second part of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, $2^{\Bbb R}$ means the set of all functions $f:\Bbb R\to\{0,1\}$. You see that there is a natural way of associating to any such function a subset of $\Bbb R$, namely $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ You can think of $f$ as marking any real number $\lambda$ as “in” if $f(\lambda)=1$ and “out” if $f(\lambda)=0$. So $2^{\Bbb R}$ and the power set of $\Bbb R$ maynot be the same thing, but they certainly are in natural one-to-one correspondence.

For your second question, such a function $\ell$ would be associating a real number (or “infinity”) to each subset of $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

$A^B$ for sets $A$ and $B$ is short for $\{\text{maps }f\colon B\rightarrow A\}$.

With $2=\{0,1\}$ "the" two-element set, indeed $2^A = P(A)$
("=" meaning that the sets are bijective).

A possible bijection $2^A\rightarrow P(A)$ is $f \mapsto f^{-1}(\{0\})$.

I am not sure what your second line is asking for.

Comment: The second line looks like the characterization of a function that takes in subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and spits out a non-negative real value, or positive infinity.